# Value of C _PyTime_t in Python

Tags: python, time

When sleeping for a long time (like running `time.sleep(3**3**3)`) in Python 3, the program returns an OverflowError with the error message "timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t". What is the largest time length I can sleep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value should be 9223372036.854775, which is "is the maximum value for a 64-bit signed integer in computing". See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

> Mentioning of `_PyTime_t` in [PEP 564](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/#cpython-enhancements-of-the-last-5-years):
>
> The CPython private "pytime" C API handling time now uses a new _PyTime_t type: simple 64-bit signed integer (C int64_t). The _PyTime_t unit is an implementation detail and not part of the API. The unit is currently 1 nanosecond.

```
>>> 2 ** 63 / 10 ** 9
9223372036.854776
>>> time.sleep(9223372036.854775)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> time.sleep(9223372036.854776)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t
>>>
```

Comment: I'm getting weird errors like "ValueError: sleep length must be non-negative" instead of OverflowError for `2**63/10**9`, but not for values a couple nanoseconds later. Very curious. See my tweet: https://twitter.com/ErikBjare/status/1559522190168670209

Comment: Firstly, 9223372036.854775 is a float, not an integer. Secondly, it too raises `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` in Python 3.11.0.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.11.0 under Ubuntu 20.04, the previous answers raise exceptions with `time.sleep`:

- `threading.TIMEOUT_MAX` raises `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`
- Using `2 ** 63 / 10 ** 9` or `(2**63 - 1)//(10**9)` raises `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

The following however works:

```py
> import datetime, time
> max_years = 292  # Ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/889b0b9bf95651fc05ad532cc4a66c0f8ff29fc2/Include/cpython/pytime.h
> sleep_time = datetime.timedelta(days=max_years * 365).total_seconds()
> sleep_time
9208512000.0
> time.sleep(sleep_time)  # This works.
```

The reason for using the defined number of years is the following comment in [`pytime.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/cpython/pytime.h):

```c
// The _PyTime_t API supports a resolution of 1 nanosecond. The _PyTime_t type
// is signed to support negative timestamps. The supported range is around
// [-292.3 years; +292.3 years]. Using the Unix epoch (January 1st, 1970), the
// supported date range is around [1677-09-21; 2262-04-11].
```

Using 292.3 failed to work from inside a Docker container based on `python:3.11-slim-buster`, raising `OSError`, but 292 worked.

---

Bonus: Here is a function to sleep for long periods, as long as +inf:

```py
def sleep_long(secs: int | float) -> None:
    """Sleep for up to an extended number of seconds, beyond what `time.sleep` may natively support."""
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74712113/
    max_secs = 9208512000  # Ref: datetime.timedelta(days=292 * 365).total_seconds()
    if secs <= max_secs:
        time.sleep(secs)
    else:
        while secs > 0:
            sleep_time = min(secs, max_secs)
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            secs -= max_secs
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following from the [documentation of the threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.TIMEOUT_MAX):

> **threading.TIMEOUT_MAX**
>
> The maximum value allowed for the timeout parameter of blocking functions (Lock.acquire(), RLock.acquire(), Condition.wait(), etc.). Specifying a timeout greater than this value will raise an OverflowError.
>
> *New in version 3.2.*

On my system, with python 3.8:

```py
>>> import threading
>>> threading.TIMEOUT_MAX
9223372036.0
```

I don't see it clearly specified anywhere that `threading.TIMEOUT_MAX` is a maximum for the argument to `time.sleep()`, but it appears to be the right value (or "close", for some reason), constructed with the same constraints.

Comment: Unfortunately, with Python 3.11.0, `time.sleep(threading.TIMEOUT_MAX)` raises `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`.