# Python how to pass infinite timeout to threading.Timer's interval argument

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading, built-in

I am using a [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) and am trying to pass in `math.inf` (+infinity) to its `interval` argument.  Please see the below sample code and traceback for exactly what I mean.

My questions are:

- How can I pass in infinity to the `interval` input to `Timer`?
- *Aside*: is this a bug in Python?

  - Do you think `Timer` should be able to handle `math.inf` as a value for the `interval` argument?

---

**Sample Code**

```py
from math import inf
from threading import Timer


def call_func_later(func, timeout_sec: float = None) -> None:
    """Call the input func after some time (sec)."""
    Timer(interval=timeout_sec or inf, function=func).start()


placeholder_func = lambda *args: None

call_func_later(placeholder_func)
```

Running this with Python 3.8.5 immediately throws the following traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1252, in run
    self.finished.wait(self.interval)
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 558, in wait
    signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 306, in wait
    gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t
```

Comment: "*How can I pass in infinity to the interval input to Timer?*" I imagine this will not be possible until we come up with a datatype and data storage hardware that can handle the value of infinity. In other words... never. Keep in mind infinity is NaN.

Comment: If you don't have a finite `timeout`, why create a timer in the first place?

Comment: @TylerH That data type is called IEEE 754 and it is able to represent + or - infinite values as well as NaN (they are two separate things). That's not the issue here.

Comment: @OP: Why are you even calling `Timer(...).start()` at all? Not starting the timer is functionally equivalent to it trying to measure infinite time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best approximation for a max is acquired from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704244/11163122

```py
# 64-bit integer, converted from nanoseconds to seconds, and subtracting 0.1
# just to be in bounds.  SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704244/11163122
MAX_TIMEOUT_SEC = 2 ** 63 / 1e9 - 0.1
```

This value is 9,223,372,036.754776 seconds, which converts to ~292 years.

As I'll probably be dead and gone by then, I will use that value instead of `math.inf`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `time.sleep(2 ** 63 / 1e9 - 0.1)` causes `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` in Python 3.11.0.

Comment: What OS are you using?  I did not get an `OSError` on my Mac with 3.11.0.

Comment: I am using GitHub Codespaces which is running Ubuntu 20.04. A Docker container using `python:3.11-slim-buster` was failing at an even lower threshold. Even so, using exactly 292 years works fine every time for me, represented as `datetime.timedelta(days=292 * 365).total_seconds()`.